# What AngularJS design pattern to use with 2 services that have a common set of fields?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I've got a situation where every solution I seem to come up with doesn't feel very "Angular" to me, so it makes me wonder if I'm missing an obvious approach somewhere. I have two services that share a common set of fields (in this case paging fields to help with paging data on a screen) -

```
app.service('service1', [function () {
        var model = this;

        model.totalItems = 0;
        model.currentPage = 1;
        model.itemsPerPage = 10;
}

app.service('service2', [function () {
        var model = this;

        model.totalItems = 0;
        model.currentPage = 1;
        model.itemsPerPage = 10;
}
```

This isn't too bad with just 3 fields, but as I've added more fields and functions I wind up duplicating a good bit of code. If I was just working with functions here, I could just share a common service between the two, but since I have data I can't use a singleton (both services need their own values in the fields). In an OO language like C# I would solve this with inheritance, but in the JS/Angular world that seems to be frowned upon because it tightly couples the services. Anyone have an approach to this that I'm missing?

Comment: "In an OO language like C# I would solve this with inheritance...", what, how in the context of your question?

Comment: You need to add your model to [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) (providing that the scope is  shared) or to [`$rootScope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) (if it's not).

Comment: You could have a factory that returns a constructor for your model.  Then in each service you just create a model that would contain all the properties. Then you only have one place to add to the model.

Comment: Khnle - Kevin Le: I would create a base service class that contained the common fields, then the two services would be defined like this - 'public service1 : baseService'. This would give both service1 and service2 fields with those names but they each would maintain their own values.

Comment: @PM77-1: You are correct that is how I have to access my services, but I'm not following how that would help the duplication of code between them.

Comment: May be I misunderstood your question.  I thought it was about not duplicating *data* by sharing it. You can have your model as a `POJ(S)O` (that will be added to the scope) and have constructor function to assign the values. Then you will code it once.

Comment: @fiskers7 That could definitely work, basically using javascripts prototypical inheritance model. My hesitation there was that seemed to be tight coupling and frowned upon in the examples I found, but it may be the path I wind up going down as it seems to make the most sense to me at the moment.

Comment: @Spencer It does tightly couple your service with a model but if the model never changes or diverges between services in any way why not use it.  One place to maintain it and only when the model changes between services would you have to break the coupling.

Comment: @fiskers7 Good points, thanks. This is the route I wound up going down, inheritance just really seems to make the most sense in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel like inheritance is the best way to model this then don't let Angular/JavaScript stop you from using it. You could set this up in Angular with something like this:

```
var ParentService = function() {
    this.totalItems = 0;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.itemsPerPage = 10;
}


var Service1 = function() {
    ParentService.call(this);
}
Service1.prototype = Object.create(ParentService.prototype);
app.service('service1', Service1);


var Service2 = function() {
    ParentService.call(this);
}
Service2.prototype = Object.create(ParentService.prototype);
app.service('service2', Service2);
```

If composition seems like a better fit you could use that instead. e.g.:

```
var ItemPageModel = function() {
    this.totalItems = 0;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.itemsPerPage = 10;
}
app.controller('itemPageModel', ItemPageModel);


var Service1 = function($controller) {
    this.model = $controller('itemPageModel');
}
Service1.$inject = ['$controller'];
app.service('service1', Service1);


var Service2 = function($controller) {
    this.model = $controller('itemPageModel');
}
Service2.$inject = ['$controller'];
app.service('service2', Service2);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the basically the route I wound up going down, using javascript's prototype inheritance.